# Multiple subdocuments in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is it possible to have multiple different subdocuments is Mongoose ? I'm creating app for online tests , and each test will have questions array containing different question types , for example true/false , multiple choice, matching and etc ... I want to create different questions schemas and questions array to contain them all. For example `questions: [QuestionSchema1, QuestionSchema2]`. Is it possible to do so ?

Schema example with basic question type down below. And what if i want do add different type of question for this test ?

```
const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  level: {
    type: String
  },
  questions: [
    {
      id: {
        type: String
      },
      question: {
        type: String
      },
      answers: [
        {
          id: {
            type: String
          },
          answer: {
            type: String
          }
        }
      ],
      validAnswerId: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this with subdocuments you can just type the the questions as an object array and put whatever you want inside it:

```
...
questions: [{
  type: Object
}],
...
```

If you are fine with creating multiple collections you can use mongooses [`refPath`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref) to do this with stricter schemas:

```
...
questions: [{
  question: {
    type: ObjectId,
    refPath: 'questions.questionType'
  },
  questionType: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['MultipleChoice', 'Matching', ...]
 },
}]
...
```

Then you can create all the different schemas you want for your questions and add their models (like `'MultipleChoice'` and `'Matching'`) to the `questionType` enum. Afterwards when you need to access the questions you just populate them with `.populate('questions')` on the query object.

Comment: Amazing @als. It would be great if you could include a full example in your response. It took me a little to understand what you meant :)

Just in case for someone else, in the [refPath](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref) link you can see a full example: